# Add Event to custom calendar crashed the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, eventkit

I am trying to add an event to custom calendar.

To fetch the calendar list I used below

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
   if(!granted) {
     //error alert
     return;
   }
   NSArray *calendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
   // List of all calendars
   // Let user to choose a calendar.
}];
```

For add an event I used the below code

```
-(void)addEvent:(EventStoreClass *)storeObject
{
    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) return;

        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        [event setTitle:[storeObject eventTitle]];
        [event setStartDate:[storeObject eventStartDate]];
        [event setEndDate:[storeObject eventEndDate]];
        [event setCalendar:[storeObject calendar] ? [storeObject calendar] : [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
    }];
}
```

Now when I used the default calendar it's successfully added but when I choose any other calendar the application get crashed and in log it's shows

> *** -[EKSource retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f9bddb1bf50

[image]

I am not able to find out the exact problem or for which line this problem arise. Any advice will be appreciable.

Comment: Since `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:` is asynch, you may have to have define `store` as `strong` property.

Comment: Not work still it's crashing in same way....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by doing the below.

```
-(void)addEvent:(EventStoreClass *)storeObject
{
    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) return;

        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        [event setTitle:[storeObject eventTitle]];
        [event setStartDate:[storeObject eventStartDate]];
        [event setEndDate:[storeObject eventEndDate]];

        if([storeObject calendar]) {
            NSArray *calendars = [store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
            __block EKCalendar *calendar;

            [calendars enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(EKCalendar *cal, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                if([[cal title] isEqualToString:[[storeObject calendar] title]]) {
                    calendar = cal;
                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }];

            [event setCalendar:calendar];
        }
        else {
            [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        }
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
    }];
}
```

The problem was on `[storeObject calendar]` as this calendar was taken from another store and we are assigning it with different store. So I just took the calendars from the same store and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether that particular calendar allows you to modify it or not

```
  if ([storeObject calendar].allowsContentModifications)
    {
      //add event now  
    }
```

Comment: it's allow but still crashed.

Comment: did you enabled NSZombie

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your store object is deallocated before completion block starts to run.

The easiest way to fix it - save store object as a field:

```
EKEventStore *store;

-(void)addEvent:(EventStoreClass *)storeObject
{
   store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) return;

        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        [event setTitle:[storeObject eventTitle]];
        [event setStartDate:[storeObject eventStartDate]];
        [event setEndDate:[storeObject eventEndDate]];
        [event setCalendar:[storeObject calendar] ? [storeObject calendar] : [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
    }];
}
```